# Excel VBA, select a block of row down

Tags: vba, excel

I have a sub like this:

```
 Sub deleteExcessData(selectSheet As String, selectRow As Integer)   
    'selectSheet = go to a certain sheet
    'selectRow = go to a certain row

 End Sub
```

What I want to do with this is select a row to start, then select all the non-blank rows below that row all the way to the bottom, then delete that selection. (this can include the row or not include that row)

I only want to use 2 variables in this sub, one is to select the sheets and on is used to select the anchor row. Data is contiguous.

What if there are some random blank cells in the data?

Any suggestion?

Comment: A modern Excel worksheet has 1,048,576 rows. Change `selectRow As Integer` to `selectRow As Long`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should remove all rows to the bottom of the worksheet including the row being called.

```
Sub test()
    Call deleteExcessData("Sheet1", 9)
End Sub

Sub deleteExcessData(selectSheet As String, selectRow As Long)
    With Sheets(selectSheet).Cells(selectRow, 1)
        .Resize(Rows.Count - selectRow + 1, 1).EntireRow.Delete
    End With
End Sub
```

The above removes all rows from 9:1048576.

You could alternately pass across the worksheet object rather than the name if that is already defined by the calling sub.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
Sub deleteExcessData(selectSheet As String, selectRow As Integer)
    lastRow = Worksheets(selectSheet).Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row
    Worksheets(selectSheet).Rows(selectRow & ":" & lastRow).Delete
End Sub
```

If you need to go up from the bottom, try this:

```
Sub deleteExcessData(selectSheet As String, selectRow As Integer)
    lastRow = Worksheets(selectSheet).Cell(Row.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Worksheets(selectSheet).Rows(selectRow & ":" & lastRow).Delete
End Sub
```

Comment: And be sure to try this out on some test data first.

Comment: how should I do it if there are a few blank cells in the data?

Comment: I believe your first sub only deletes row 1,048,576. You have not extended the range reference from the start to the bottom.

Comment: So I tried your code (the first part) with this: Call deleteExcessData("data", 5) and it gives me "object does not support this property or method".     And your second code gives me "object required" on the second row. I already declared a global lastRow variable as Long.

Comment: Does it point you to a line where the error occurs? Also be sure to try @Jeeped's answer.

Comment: The first piece of code has error on the second code line. The second piece also has error on second code line.

Comment: That's strange, it should be working. Check out the other solution.

Comment: I think the problem with the second may be `Row.Count` when it should be `Rows.Count` . Personally, I would not recommend the first if there is any chance of a blank cell within the data on column A. I've also found that `.EntireRow` is often expected even when dealing with `.Rows(...)` .